# boost crc yields different output each time

Tags: c++, boost, crc16, catch-unit-test

**Background**

I am trying to calculate CRC-16/CRC2 for a given byte array using boost crc lib.

Note: I am a beginner at best in C++ development

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/crc.hpp>

namespace APP{
    class CrcUtil{
        public:
            static uint16_t crc16(const std::vector<uint8_t> input) {
                boost::crc_16_type result;
                result.process_bytes(&input, input.size());
                return result.checksum();
            }

            CrcUtil()=delete;
    };
};
```

I am using catch2 as my test framework. Here is the code for test:

```
#include "catch.hpp"

#include "../include/crcUtil.h"

TEST_CASE("is crc calculation correct", "[crcUtil.h TESTS]"){
    std::vector<uint8_t> bytes = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};
    auto expectedCRC2 = 0x3c9d;
    auto actualCRC2 = APP::CrcUtil::crc16(bytes);

    REQUIRE(expectedCRC2 == actualCRC2);
}
```

**Issue**

Each time I ran my test calculated CRC is different.

First run:

```
/.../test/crcUtilTests.cpp:10: FAILED:
    REQUIRE( expectedCRC2 == actualCRC2 )
with expansion:
    15517 (0x3c9d) == 63180
```

Second run:

```
/.../test/crcUtilTests.cpp:10: FAILED:
    REQUIRE( expectedCRC2 == actualCRC2 )
with expansion:
    15517 (0x3c9d) == 33478
```

Nth run:

```
/.../test/crcUtilTests.cpp:10: FAILED:
    REQUIRE( expectedCRC2 == actualCRC2 )
with expansion:
    15517 (0x3c9d) == 47016
```

**Question**

Is there something wrong with my code?

Why CRC16 is different for same input?

How can reliably calculate CRC16 for a given byte array?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write a good question, with all the necessary code and details!

Comment: Learning how to properly ask a technical question have saved me many times in the past. I am glad that I could express my problem properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
&input
```

This does **not** give you a pointer to the data buffer! It gives you a pointer to the `vector` object itself, so you are interpreting the internals of that object as the data buffer. It will be different every time because it contains things like dynamically allocated pointers to the real data buffer.

Also, the object representation of the `vector` probably isn't the same size as `input.size()`, and may have some [padding bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) too. So most likely you are also invoking [**Undefined Behaviour**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by reading uninitialised memory, meaning **your program is completely invalid** and **anything could happen** (including appearing to work normally).

Use [`input.data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) to get a pointer to the contained data, like this:

```
result.process_bytes(input.data(), input.size());
```

Comment: Yet another rookie mistake, I never learn. Thank you for informative answer.

Comment: Haha, we are all always learning, we've all done plenty of things like this! Maybe you meant to type `&input[0]`, which was a common pattern before `.data()` was added in C++11? (Giving you a way to save face here )